# How to power on AWS instance with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Sorry I am very new to Terraform.

I create AWS instance with Terraform successfully.
Then I power off the instance in AWS web management console.

How to power on the instance with Terraform?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html) to run AWS CLI's [start-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/start-instances.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [instance_type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#instance_type) value of aws_instance terraform resource.

```
instance_type : (Optional) The instance type to use for the instance.  
Updates to this field will trigger a stop/start of the EC2 instance.
```